# Reloading tinymce.init function on ajax call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, ruby-on-rails-2, tinymce-4

I'm on `rails 2`, using `tinymce 4` editor for `textarea` field.

**new.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<%= render "form" %>
<% form_for ... %>
 <%= c.text_area :description %>
 <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

*I need to refresh below script*

**_form.html**

```
<div id ="refresh_editor">
<script type="text/javascript">
  tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
...
..
});
</div>
```

**.rjs file**

```
page.replace_html 'refresh_editor', :partial => 'form'
```

My question,
1) How to refresh the script?
 
2) Do I need to refresh the text area type as well?, which will then make content in the editor empty.

Why i'm doing this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ndS7/1/) will give an idea, I would loose values when the user checks the paper margin dropdown for the second time.

Comment: put script inside a function and call it whenever you want that

Comment: @NitinJ yes, but how to a load the script on ajax calls? I know I could change forms or text, but the script would be loaded to page once for all, my thoughts are right? so how to call the js function?

Comment: do you want to run that script on page load as well as on AJAX request . or just on ajax request

Comment: i've found a way to run it on page load, but how to do it on ajax call?

Comment: $.ajax({ url: "/users/check_login", success: function(data){ //here call your function for that script}})

Answer (score -1):

uhm... say me if i understand correctly:
You need to re-initialize the tinymce script?

If you need to do this maybe you can find inside the tinymce documentation if there is a method for re-inizialize or reset the script.

Howerver i find inside tinymce object the method `tinymce.remove()`, you can use it to remove and re-initialize the script (i try to use it for re-init but it suck :D).

So, simply create a function (or in my example e method of tinymce) that re-call `tinymce.init()` width your settings.

If you only need to blank the text i crate in my example a method of tinymce called `clean` that remove all content and replace it with `<p></p>`.

See the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4ndS7/3/

NOTE: i create 2 `<a>` tag for trigger the function: `clean()` and `reset()`.

It's maybe not be the best way to do this... but... is only think i can do for solve your problem.

Comment: noooo.. retain values in the tinymce window manager after initial entry, got me?

Comment: `tinymce.init(..)` to be reloaded on ajax request.. possible?

Comment: yes, you can insert `tinymce.init(..)` inside the done callback function of a ajax request.

but i'm sorry i dont' understand what you mean **noooo.. retain values in the tinymce window manager after initial entry, got me?**

you not want to retain your default settings?

Comment: i'm not worried about the settings. I'll explain the prob., after entering a value in text-box for margin top(as you saw in fiddle) and when you submit, I've used remote function in my app. and then values disappear from editor right? so I've used ajax to update the form, but I need to reload the script how can I do it? so the values would be updated in the editor.. any doubts I can go down town explaining..